# Get Dates of a Certain Weekday from a Year in R

Tags: r

How might I generate a list of date objects (POSIXct or lt) for each Monday of a year?

For instance this year would be (In Year, Month, Day):

```
2012_01_02,
2012_01_09,
2102_01_16,
etc
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT**: On further reflection, here's a cleaner function for doing the same thing:

```
getAllMondays <- function(year) {
    days <- as.POSIXlt(paste(year, 1:366, sep="-"), format="%Y-%j")
    Ms <- days[days$wday==1]
    Ms[!is.na(Ms)]  # Needed to remove NA from day 366 in non-leap years
}
getAllMondays(2012)
```

---

Here's a function that'll perform the more general task of **finding** the first Monday in an arbitrary year, and then listing it and all of the other Mondays in that year. It uses `seq.POSIXt()`, and the argument `by = "week"` (which is also available for `seq.Date()`).

```
getAllMondays <- function(year) {
    day1 <- as.POSIXlt(paste(year, "01-01", sep="-"))
    day365 <- as.POSIXlt(paste(year, "12-31", sep="-"))

    # Find the first Monday of year
    week1 <- as.POSIXlt(seq(day1, length.out=7, by="day"))
    monday1 <- week1[week1$wday == 1]

    # Return all Mondays in year
    seq(monday1, day365, by="week")
}

head(getAllMondays(2012))
# [1] "2012-01-02 PST" "2012-01-09 PST" "2012-01-16 PST" "2012-01-23 PST"
# [5] "2012-01-30 PST" "2012-02-06 PST"
```

Answer (score 4):

I found `seq.Date` which is part of `base`. Not sure if there are caveats to this method but it seems to do what I want:

```
x = seq(as.Date("2012/01/02"), as.Date("2013/01/01"), "7 days")
as.POSIXct(x)
```

Comment: If you're spending much time in date-math land, I would also familiarize yourself with Hadley's `lubridate` package.  It has some great functions to do this kind of thing.  `as.POSIXct('2012-01-02') + 1:52*new_duration(days=7)`

Answer (score 1):

```
as.Date("2012_01_02", format="%Y_%m_%d") +seq(0,366,by=7)  # 2012 is a leap year.
```

If you really want them as DateTimes with all the attendant hassles of timezones then you can coerce them with `as.POSIXct`.