# Dates of a given weekday in R

Tags: r, date

I want the dates of a given weekday (let´s say Fridays) between this two dates:

```
selectedMonths <- c(  "201002",
                      "201103"
                    )
```

How can I store them in a data.frame, the desire results is:

```
    Date
2010-02-05
2010-02-12
2010-02-19
...
2011-03-04
2011-03-11
2011-03-18
2011-03-25
```

I want to include the Fridays of the last date `"201103`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Dates of a Certain Weekday from a Year in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166437/get-dates-of-a-certain-weekday-from-a-year-in-r).  Also related: [generate dataframe of Friday dates for the year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671139/r-generate-dataframe-of-friday-dates-for-the-year)

Comment: Not exactly, given I want the dates of a week day between two months of different years, not the whole year

Comment: I look at the answers to those questions, and I see how to answer your question.  In the first link, Kyle Brandt offered this answer, which you can adapt: `x = seq(as.Date("2012/01/02"), as.Date("2013/01/01"), "7 days")`.  In the second link, thelatemail wrote a function `pick.wkday` which you should be able to use.  Make sure to look through all the answers & Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry for insists but with those answers I cannot solve my problem given my data selectedMonths <- c(  "201002", "201103"). I want the result posted in my question

Comment: dates <- seq.Date(as.Date(startdates[1]),as.Date(end),by="1 day")
dates[weekdays(dates)==dayName]
allRelatedDates<-data.frame(dates[format(dates,"%w")==5])
colnames(allRelatedDates) <- c("SelectedDates")
dim(allRelatedDates)

Comment: Format your dates, then apply a solution.  For instance, `dates <- as.Date(paste0(selectedMonths, "01"), format = "%Y%m%d"); pick.wkday(5, dates[1], dates[2])`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using `lubridate` and `dplyr`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

startdates <- ymd(paste0(selectedMonths, "01"))

df <- data.frame(dates = seq(startdates[1], startdates[2], by = "day"))

df %>%
  mutate(weekday = weekdays(dates)) %>%
  filter(weekday == "Friday")
```

Comment: My solution based on yours: startdates <- ymd(paste0(selectedMonths, "01"))
df <- data.frame(dates = seq(startdates[1], startdates[1] + months(1) - days(1), by = "day"))
filterDates <- df %>% mutate(weekday = weekdays(dates)) %>% filter(weekday == "Sunday")
filterDates[,1]